# Full-width Nav bar centered-right with content area

Tags: html, css, nav, menubar, navbar

I'm having trouble with centering my full-width navbar with my fixed content area. The ul changes with browser or resolution.

here is a fiddle with my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/fwyNy/

[subject site](http://usplumbingshop.com)

css:

```
#topribbon{
width: 100%; 
height: 30px; 
background-color: #AA1119 ; 
margin: -11px 0px 1em 0px; 
position: fixed; 
z-index: 9999; 
}
#topribbon ul{
width:auto;
padding-top:5px;
margin:0px 385px 0px auto;
float:right;
}

#topribbon ul li{
float:right;
color:white;
padding:0 10px 0 10px;
list-style:none;
display:block;
line-height:20px;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
width:auto;
}

#topribbon ul li:hover{
color:#5C8FA5;

}
```

and here is the html:

```
<div id="topribbon">  <ul>
        <li>Free Ground Shipping on all orders over $99!</li>
        <li>Why Us?</li>
        <li>Account</li>
        <li>Cart</li>
        <li>+1-800-555-5555</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Your nav bar seems centered ok

Comment: the ul is not fixed to its position. Its not responsive to different browsers and resolutions.  Im trying to have my ul always fixed to the right side of my content area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the inner ul a position:relative, a width and then use margin: 0 auto

```
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
width:980px; (for example)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fwyNy/2/
(stretch the space of the 'result')

Comment: I think this solution with `text-align: right` also applied to the `ul` would give the result notcho nachos is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try

http://jsfiddle.net/Xxm76/34/

```
     .lContent {width: 200px; border: 2px solid #000; border-right: none; float: right;   position: relative;}
   .rContent {width: 300px; border: 2px solid #000; border-left: none; float:left; position: relative;}
```

it d be cross-browser stable ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of how I would do it:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>Free Ground </li>
                <li>Why Us?</li>
                <li>Account</li>
                <li>Cart</li>
                <li>555-5555</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
    #wrapper{
    height: 5em;
    background: #000090;
    padding-top: 2em;
}
#outer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    background: #000;
}
#nav{
    height: 3em;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: right;
}
#nav>ul>li{
     width: auto;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fqTwN/